# Tor Browser will not start and I am getting the error message in the attached image. I want to solve it without resetting my PC

Tags: tor

It gives the same error even after reinstalling.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is discussed in the post
[RSA_get0_d could not be located in the dynamic link library tor.exe](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/33702).

There were two workarounds suggested in this post:

1. Setting TOR's `firefox.exe` to run in Windows 7 compatibility mode:

   - Right-click on TOR's firefox.exe, and select Properties
   - In the "Compatibility" tab, check the box that says
     "Run this program in compatibility mode for",
     and set the dropdown box to Windows 7
2. Run Tor once (only) as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly